# I cant install old nvidia driver after kernel update

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, 20.04, nvidia-geforce

i upgraded my ubuntu to 20.04 and the kernel to 5.4.0-33 , and now i cant install 390.87 nvidia driver and i can install only 390.132
my gpu : NVIDIA GeForce GT 610 
my gaming performance is better on 390.87
now what have i do ?

Comment: You can't do anything. And it is very unlikely that 390.87 has better performance. How can you compare if you can't install it on 20.04?

Answer (score -1):

You have not given the details on *How you tried to install, why you were not able to install (error message, etc), what exactly is the difference in performance that you noticed*. It is always a good practice to provide as much (relevant) info as possible. It will help you get a quick & proper solution (or) at least, more closer options - besides helping/motivating the people who are trying to help.

If the driver is showing as the **Recommended** driver under **Activities -> Additional Drivers**, then it the latest **stable** legacy driver that supports your Ubuntu version & kernel version - according to Ubuntu.

Judging by the version number, the one that is installed now, seems to be the more later (if not latest) subversion of **Nvidia 390** driver family. However, at times latest kernels & latest drivers don't go hand in hand.

You can install a particular version of NVIDIA driver by downloading it from official NVIDIA site (link below).

[https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/137276/en-us](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/137276/en-us/)

**Note:** This is for 64-bit GPU. If you have 32-bit, browse back in the site & select the appropriate one.

> Now, before installing the particular version, you need to remove the
> currently installed version(s). Follow the link below for
> instructions.
>
> [Ubuntu 18.10 : How can I install a specific NVIDIA drivers version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097433/ubuntu-18-10-how-can-i-install-a-specific-nvidia-drivers-version)

The download is a file with `.run` extension, and can installed by using just `sh` command (like below).

```
sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.125.run
```

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to explain why you've down-voted it? In case you're wondering... No, I'm not offended.. just curious to know what's wrong.