# Can't go back to older nvidia driver on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, graphics

I'm on Ubuntu 20 using Nvidia RTX GPU

I'm experiencing some slowdowns after updating from driver435 to driver460.
I wanted to go back to driver435, and when I want to rollback, it says:

- nvidia-driver-435 : Depends: nvidia-driver-455 but it is not going to be installed

I don't understand how it's possible that an older driver depends on a newer driver.
Do you have an idea on how to use the nvidia-driver-435 on Ubuntu 20.04 ?

ps: I've already tried this: [Ubuntu 18.10 : How can I install a specific NVIDIA drivers version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097433/ubuntu-18-10-how-can-i-install-a-specific-nvidia-drivers-version) and as I say, it automatically installs newer versions.

Thanks for any answer!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to solve this after running `sudo apt purge libnvidia*`