# Suspend not working properly (cannot wake up) on Ubuntu 20.04 with NVIDIA

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, suspend, hp

My problem is that I cannot suspend my computer properly. Technically I can, but when I come back and try to reopen it, it just doesn't work. My screen remains black with a blinking line, like a typical writing line `_`.

My laptop is a [HP Pavilion 15-BC519NS Intel Core i5-9300H/8GB/512GB SSD/GTX 1050/15.6"](https://www.pccomponentes.com/hp-pavilion-15-bc519ns-intel-core-i5-9300h-8gb-512gb-ssd-gtx-1050-156).

Here is the output of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core 4-core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [Coffee Lake H] (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 10)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1d.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #14 (rev f0)
00:1d.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #15 (rev f0)
00:1d.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #16 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM470 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 3 GB Max-Q] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller (rev ff)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
04:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
05:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

I haven't seen a fix for this anywhere, so I was expecting someone to help me here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you do `alt ->`(that is an alt right) arrow and get to a login? If so I can show you how to restart the gui

Comment: Hey Nate, i was playing a little bit with suspending, and indeed idk what i did (i guess pressed alt right) and it asked me for my login. Although it didnt let me write anything and also it didnt let me do anything, i seemed like it was frozen.

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 NVIDIA 470/510 `nv_restore_user_channels` bug + workaround:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032633/18-04-screen-remains-blank-after-wake-up-from-suspend/1391917#1391917

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suspect that your problem is related to the latest NVIDIA update, which installs `nvidia-driver-460`. There is currently a bug with this version and some versions after it. You can subscribe to the bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-460/+bug/1911055

You can workaround the issue until the bug gets resolved by downgrading the NVIDIA driver to a previous version. Follow these steps to downgrade to `nvidia-driver-450-server`:

1. Open Software & Updates and go to the *Additional Drivers* tab.
2. Select `nvidia-driver-450-server` (*Using NVIDIA Server Driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-450-server (proprietary)*).

   [image: Additional Drivers]

   You may try other drivers instead of `nvidia-driver-450-server`, if you wish, and stay with the one that works best for you.
3. Click *Apply Changes* and wait until the changes are applied.
4. Restart your system.

Suspend should now work as expected!

Comment: Oh shit it worked, thanks!!!!!

Comment: If you want to be aware about how to change it from console, these commands would be useful: `sudo apt purge nvidia-driver-460`, `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-418-server` and reboot  (change versions acordingly to your system/choices). More details here: https://linoxide.com/how-to-install-nvidia-driver-on-ubuntu/

Comment: If some one has this issue with latest `495` drivers.
use this suggestions https://gist.github.com/bmcbm/375f14eaa17f88756b4bdbbebbcfd029#gistcomment-3973785

Answer (score 6):

FIX for suspend-resume problem - black screen on resume
Ubuntu 20.04LTS, 5.13.0, nvidia-drivers 510

Two parts:

1. Earlier versions of nvidia drivers required support for suspend/resume/hibernate in `/etc/systemd/`

   These support scripts MUST be removed for nvidia-driver-470 onwards using:

   ```
   sudo systemctl disable nvidia-suspend
   sudo systemctl disable nvidia-resume
   sudo systemctl disable nvidia-hibernate
   ```

   They are NOT automatically removed during driver update and systems with nvidia drivers installed before 470 have them left behind after upgrade.  This might be the reason why many people suggest reverting back to 460.
2. `/usr/bin/nvidia-sleep.sh` needs to still be deactivated by an immediate exit. Add a line just after the bash header line to cause immediate exit 0 (ie success) from the script:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   exit 0
   ```

With those two sets of changes suspend/resume now works correctly for me.

Comment: Hmm - this worked for a while then reverted.  Back to the black screen again - sigh.

Comment: See also: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/nouveau/-/issues/49

Comment: For the 2nd step, if you've disable the `/proc/driver/nvidia/suspend` route of power management (presumably from step 1), then this is redundant. O.w. the default script should suffice:

```#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -f /proc/driver/nvidia/suspend ]; then
    exit 0
fi
...```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue on an Acer Aspire laptop running Ubuntu 20.04 with NVIDIA. I was using the default driver (`nvidia-driver-460`). I then tried `nvidia-driver-450-server` and still didn't have any luck. Then I tried `nvidia-driver-418-server` and it worked.

Here is my *Additional Drivers* tab in Software & Updates:

[image: Additional Drivers tab in Software & Updates]

My advice: keep rolling back the driver and testing until you find one that works.

1. Open Software & Updates → *Additional Drivers* tab.
2. Select `nvidia-driver-418-server`.
3. Click *Apply Changes*.
4. Reboot system.
5. Test suspend.

Comment: Have you tried "nvidia-driver-465" which seems newer ?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't work for me. `nvidia-driver-418-server` is the newest version that seems to work on my system. I have a GEFORCE 940MX video card.

Comment: Rolling back until you find one that works -  what a lousy solution.

Answer (score 2):

Quoted below is my explanation of the problem and answer on the duplicate thread [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1335689/ubuntu-20-04-lts-can-not-resume-after-suspending/1436921#1436921).

> A little background to understand the problem and the redundancy of
> some of the suggested (working) solutions.
>
> The NVIDIA Linux driver supports the suspend and hibernate power
> management operations via two different mechanisms:
>
> 1. **Kernel driver callback**: default mechanism - it is enabled and used without explicit configuration. The kernel driver receives
>    callbacks from the Linux kernel to suspend, hibernate, and to resume
>    each GPU for which a Linux PCI driver was registered.
> 2. `/proc/driver/nvidia/suspend`: Instead of callbacks from the Linux kernel, this mechanism, when used, relies on a system management tool,
>    such as `systemd`, to issue suspend, hibernate, and resume commands to
>    the NVIDIA kernel driver via the `/proc/driver/nvidia/suspend`
>    interface. It is still considered experimental, and requires explicit
>    configuration to use.
>
> The **cleanest easy solution** is to simply *disable 2 (if enabled)
> and let the default mechanism [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLbWA.png) do the work*.
>
> Of course, advanced users can choose to fix [2] with explicit and
> accurate configuration - it is more powerful as this mechanism is
> designed to remove the limitations of the kernel driver callback
> mechanism [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLbWA.png). It supports power management with advanced CUDA
> features (such as UVM), and it is capable of saving and restoring all
> video memory allocations
>
> Here are the steps for *cleanest easy solution* (`su -` access
> presumed):
>
> 1. Check whether [2] is enabled:
>
>    ```
>    systemctl status nvidia-suspend nvidia-hibernate nvidia-resume
>    ```
>
>    [image]
> 2. Alternatively, do:
>
>    ```
>    journalctl -b | grep suspend
>    ```
>
>    If [2] is being used, you'll see it action explicitly in the logs
>    like:
>
>    ```
>    COMMAND=/bin/systemctl status nvidia-suspend nvidia-hibernate nvidia-resume
>    ```
> 3. Okay, now that you know [2] is in use, let's disable it.:
>
>    ```
>    systemctl disable nvidia-suspend nvidia-hibernate nvidia-resume
>    ```
>
>    You should see a message stating:
>
>    ```
>    Removed /etc/systemd/system/systemd-[suspend|hibernate|resume].service.requires/nvidia-[suspend|hibernate|resume].service
>    ```
> 4. Now, you can repeat steps 1 or 2 and verify that the service(s) is/are indeed *disabled*:
>
>    ```
>    rm /lib/systemd/system-sleep/nvidia
>    ```
>
> I've seen some working but inaccurate solutions like
> [[1](https://gist.github.com/bmcbm/375f14eaa17f88756b4bdbbebbcfd029?permalink_comment_id=4030146#gistcomment-4030146),
> [2](https://gist.github.com/bmcbm/375f14eaa17f88756b4bdbbebbcfd029?permalink_comment_id=4184379#gistcomment-4184379),
> [3](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1933880/comments/9)],
> where manual `sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/systemd-suspend.service.requires/nvidia-suspend.service`
> is suggested. You should NOT do this.
>
> Some other useful commands for diagnostics:
>
> `$ cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version  $ nvcc --version`
>
> Also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> followed by
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.