# Ubuntu 20.04 not suspending on Alienware

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, suspend

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on an Alienware 17 R4 with an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070. I recently did a software update which caused the system not to resume after suspend so I changed the driver from proprietary tested to proprietary server (version 460 on both).

Now the system won't suspend at all. It basically reboots when suspending from the GUI or terminal. I've tried editing the GRUB file by adding:

```
mem_sleep_default=deep
```

to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line editing the `logind.conf` file to no avail.

I ran `dmesg` in the terminal and received these errors:

```
[    0.510392] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x200] vs fed40080 f80
[    0.510399] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x200] vs fed40080 f80

[  120.186484] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_GPE.PGWA due to previous error (AE_AML_LOOP_TIMEOUT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[  120.186564] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_GPE._E37 due to previous error (AE_AML_LOOP_TIMEOUT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[  120.186582] ACPI Error: AE_AML_LOOP_TIMEOUT, while evaluating GPE method [_E37] (20190816/evgpe-511)
```

I've been at this all day and haven't found a solution. This is my work computer so I need this resolved quickly. Right now I have suspend on battery power turned off. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suspend not working properly (cannot wake up) on Ubuntu 20.04 with NVIDIA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345073/suspend-not-working-properly-cannot-wake-up-on-ubuntu-20-04-with-nvidia)

Answer (score 0):

So I solved this issue just by reverting back to the 450 server nvidia driver.