# Ubuntu 21.04 can't turn on after suspending

Tags: suspend, freeze, 21.04

When I try using suspend, the laptop will not resume; I have to do a hard reset. The machine will also freeze while booting. How can I fix this?

Info about my system:

[image: system info]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suspend not working properly (cannot wake up) on Ubuntu 20.04 with NVIDIA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345073/suspend-not-working-properly-cannot-wake-up-on-ubuntu-20-04-with-nvidia)