# Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS freezes after being suspend

Tags: 20.04, suspend

The issue happened all of a sudden without any new software installation or updates (to my knowledge).

After I try to wake up the computer I get a white cursor on the screen and when I press `CTRL` + `ALT` + `F7` I can see the following output:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p6: recovering journal
/dev/nvme0n1p6: Clearing orphaned inode 3019465 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=010060
...
...
/dev/nvme0n1p6: clean, 2591309/12058624 files, 26099507/48227072 blocks
```

I already tried setting `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` in `/etc/default/grub` to both `nouveau.blacklist=1` and `nouveau.modeset=0`. Neither worked.

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Kernel version: 5.8.0-59-generic

Video card: GTX 1060 Mobile with nvidia-driver-460

Comment: Do you have multiple monitors? I have similar behavior sometimes, using Asus notebook with external monitor connected. As a temporary workarround, try disconnect secondary monitor before computer suspends.

Comment: @MauricioID yes, I'm using the exact same setup as you - a laptop with an external monitor. 

I just managed to solve the issue by moving to nvidia-driver-450. You can check [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345073/suspend-not-working-properly-cannot-wake-up-on-ubuntu-20-04-with-nvidia) provided in the other comment: