# 21.04 black screen after suspend integrated GPU

Tags: suspend, intel-graphics, 21.04

Did a clean install of 21.04. Screen is black when waking from suspend.

Edit - What I did so far:

nouveau.modeset=0 in grub

Tried with ASPM set to L1 and L1L0s

gdm3 to lightdm

Edit2 - Updating to kernel 5.13.1 worked. Now I'm praying that I can get the Tesla K80 working as well.

Edit3 - `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` then installing driver 465 did not yield error. Getting error from the driver during use though. It prevents the computer to sleep after launching a couple of app (sleep work if I don't do anything).  :(

Edit4 (last) - Putting the axe on 21.04. I don't think 5.13.1 is compatible with nvidia's drivers yet. Going for 20.04 Kubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suspend not working properly (cannot wake up) on Ubuntu 20.04 with NVIDIA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345073/suspend-not-working-properly-cannot-wake-up-on-ubuntu-20-04-with-nvidia)

Comment: No, I tried all suggested driver and same issue. :(

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my Asus Zenbook 13 running Ubuntu 20.04. I didn't have any drivers listed in Software & Updates > Additional Drivers (as I didn't have a dedicated GPU).

I experimented further, nonetheless, and under the Developer Options tab I checked Pre-released updates (focal-proposed). After that I updated the system (`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y`) and just like that the suspend error was gone and so far I haven't come across any bugs after installing the proposed updates...