# Black screen with unblinking cursor on sleep

Tags: 20.04, suspend, lid

I have a Lenovo Ideapad 310 wit an NVIDIA 920M graphics card. I recently dual booted Ubuntu and I didn't have any problems. I've never put my laptop to sleep nor closed the lid without shutting it down.

So today, for the first time, I closed the lid, without powering off, expecting it to be put in sleep mode and ready to work again when opened. When I opened my laptop, there was a black screen with a cursor. The cursor wasn't blinking, unlike every other similar problem I find via google and on here.

I tried updating the drivers with `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` everything was already up to date. I also tried a lot of key combinations with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>something_else</kbd> but nothing worked.

Comment: Did you try this: [Suspend not working properly (cannot wake up) on Ubuntu 20.04 with NVIDIA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345073/suspend-not-working-properly-cannot-wake-up-on-ubuntu-20-04-with-nvidia/1345212#1345212)

Comment: Yes It works. Thanks, I didn't see it before !