# Ubuntu 21.04 won't wake from sleep

Tags: suspend, asus

Ubuntu is on version 21.04, Gnome is on version 3.38.5. My device is an Asus TUF F15 laptop.

So what happens is if I accidentally trigger my laptop to sleep, I'm greeted with an unlock screen when I get back in. But past that is a black screen with a terminal cursor that I can type in-- no command prompts or anything, it's kind of like a really weird text editor-- sometimes starting with a series of `^@` repeating.

I am able to go to other TTYs but I lack the expertise to know how to, like, kill whatever's in the affected one and restart it, I don't want to lose whatever I was doing(?) etc.

What should I do to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: What does this statement in your question mean? The about page also mentions Gnome is at 3.38.5 if that makes a difference  Another vague statement press the sleep button or anything, Please edit the question and make it more clear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suspend not working properly (cannot wake up) on Ubuntu 20.04 with NVIDIA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345073/suspend-not-working-properly-cannot-wake-up-on-ubuntu-20-04-with-nvidia)

Comment: I'm actually using the xorg nouveau driver...

Comment: Setting it to nvidia-driver-470 works now.

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 NVIDIA 470/510 `nv_restore_user_channels` bug + workaround:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032633/18-04-screen-remains-blank-after-wake-up-from-suspend/1391917#1391917