# Ubuntu wakes up immediately from sleep after NVIDIA driver update

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, suspend, nouveau

I was using the Nouveau X.org driver for my graphics card, but today I changed the driver to nvidia-driver-470 (proprietary and tested) from the "additional drivers" program in Ubuntu.
Everything is fine, except that whenever I suspend my laptop, it wakes up itself immediately.

Here is the output of the following command:

```
journalctl -b | grep suspend
```

the output is

```
Sep 24 22:26:38 minaHP ModemManager[1527]: <info>  [sleep-monitor] system is about to suspend
Sep 24 22:26:39 minaHP systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA system suspend actions...
Sep 24 22:26:39 minaHP suspend[518255]: nvidia-suspend.service
Sep 24 22:26:39 minaHP logger[518255]: <13>Sep 24 22:26:39 suspend: nvidia-suspend.service
Sep 24 22:26:39 minaHP systemd[518256]: nvidia-suspend.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory
Sep 24 22:26:39 minaHP systemd[518256]: nvidia-suspend.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/bin/nvidia-sleep.sh: No such file or directory
Sep 24 22:26:39 minaHP systemd[1]: nvidia-suspend.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Sep 24 22:26:39 minaHP systemd[1]: nvidia-suspend.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 24 22:26:39 minaHP systemd[1]: Failed to start NVIDIA system suspend actions.
Sep 24 22:26:39 minaHP systemd[1]: suspend.target: Job suspend.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Sep 24 22:26:39 minaHP systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Job systemd-suspend.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Sep 24 22:26:39 minaHP suspend[518257]: nvidia-resume.service
Sep 24 22:26:39 minaHP logger[518257]: <13>Sep 24 22:26:39 suspend: nvidia-resume.service
```

if anyone can tell me how to fix this without changing the driver back to Nouveau, it would be great.

Here is another command and its output if it is helpful

```
mina@minaHP:~$ systemctl status nvidia-suspend nvidia-hibernate nvidia-resume
● nvidia-suspend.service - NVIDIA system suspend actions
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nvidia-suspend.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2021-09-24 22:26:39 EET; 12min ago
    Process: 518255 ExecStart=/usr/bin/logger -t suspend -s nvidia-suspend.service (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 518256 ExecStart=/usr/bin/nvidia-sleep.sh suspend (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
   Main PID: 518256 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Sep 24 22:26:39 minaHP systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA system suspend actions...
Sep 24 22:26:39 minaHP suspend[518255]: nvidia-suspend.service
Sep 24 22:26:39 minaHP logger[518255]: <13>Sep 24 22:26:39 suspend: nvidia-suspend.service
Sep 24 22:26:39 minaHP systemd[518256]: nvidia-suspend.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory
Sep 24 22:26:39 minaHP systemd[518256]: nvidia-suspend.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/bin/nvidia-sleep.sh: No such file or directory
Sep 24 22:26:39 minaHP systemd[1]: nvidia-suspend.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Sep 24 22:26:39 minaHP systemd[1]: nvidia-suspend.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 24 22:26:39 minaHP systemd[1]: Failed to start NVIDIA system suspend actions.

● nvidia-hibernate.service - NVIDIA system hibernate actions
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nvidia-hibernate.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)

● nvidia-resume.service - NVIDIA system resume actions
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nvidia-resume.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2021-09-24 22:26:39 EET; 12min ago
    Process: 518257 ExecStart=/usr/bin/logger -t suspend -s nvidia-resume.service (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 518258 ExecStart=/usr/bin/nvidia-sleep.sh resume (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
   Main PID: 518258 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Sep 24 22:26:39 minaHP systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA system resume actions...
Sep 24 22:26:39 minaHP suspend[518257]: nvidia-resume.service
Sep 24 22:26:39 minaHP logger[518257]: <13>Sep 24 22:26:39 suspend: nvidia-resume.service
Sep 24 22:26:39 minaHP systemd[518258]: nvidia-resume.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory
Sep 24 22:26:39 minaHP systemd[518258]: nvidia-resume.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/bin/nvidia-sleep.sh: No such file or directory
Sep 24 22:26:39 minaHP systemd[1]: nvidia-resume.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Sep 24 22:26:39 minaHP systemd[1]: nvidia-resume.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 24 22:26:39 minaHP systemd[1]: Failed to start NVIDIA system resume actions.
```

Comment: Try changing your driver through *Additional Drivers* to a previous one that works. Follow the steps shown in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1345212/618353).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These errors appear cause you have to install **NVIDIA-{suspend/hibernate/resume} services**.

Something like this:

```
sudo install /usr/share/doc/NVIDIA_GLX-1.0/samples/systemd/nvidia-suspend.service /etc/systemd/system
sudo install /usr/share/doc/NVIDIA_GLX-1.0/samples/systemd/nvidia-hibernate.service /etc/systemd/system
sudo install /usr/share/doc/NVIDIA_GLX-1.0/samples/systemd/nvidia-resume.service /etc/systemd/system
sudo install /usr/share/doc/NVIDIA_GLX-1.0/samples/systemd/nvidia /lib/systemd/system-sleep
sudo install /usr/share/doc/NVIDIA_GLX-1.0/samples/systemd/nvidia-sleep.sh /usr/bin
```

The NVIDIA `systemd` services then need to be enabled:

```
sudo systemctl enable nvidia-suspend.service
sudo systemctl enable nvidia-hibernate.service
sudo systemctl enable nvidia-resume.service
```

Reinstalling the NVIDIA driver should help.

Comment: Those paths for the docs are not present on my system

Comment: @Alkanshel I'm on a different distro and installed through APT. The .service files were in `/lib/systemd/system`