# Ubuntu 23.04 - Won't wake from suspend

Tags: nvidia, suspend, video, screen, reboot

Recently updated from 22.10 to 23.04, now struggling to wake up laptop when waking from suspend on a Dell Precision M4800 with Nvidia graphics. The power button and the volume buttons light up solid but there is nothing on the screen and I have to do a hard restart, any ideas where to begin?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suspend not working properly (cannot wake up) on Ubuntu 20.04 with NVIDIA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345073/suspend-not-working-properly-cannot-wake-up-on-ubuntu-20-04-with-nvidia)

Comment: @popey it's unlikely that the problem is the same since that problem was reported way before Ubuntu 23.04 release. Also, the problem is different, here the leds are on but screen blank, in the other there is a blinking dash .

Comment: I have the same problem, and it is after updating from Ubuntu 22.10 to 23.04 too. But my system does not have an Nvidia graphics card, I'm on a Lenovo legion Y520 intel + Radeon. It doesn't always happen, but I'm feeling like it's happening more and more frequently.

Comment: It seems to be because of this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe-5.19/+bug/2008774, I just tried to suspend twice, and the second was the one that failed, can you confirm and vote up Daniel?

Comment: I spoke too soon, I was able to replicate that once, after the system was running for some hours, but after restart, I could suspend many times without problem. So I guess it's something that happens after some time of use, probably when more RAM is used. The last is just a wild guess.

Comment: Well, it seems the problem occurs if suspended while locked, I disabled auto suspend because I don't want to lose my job if I leave my laptop unattended for too long and forgot to save it. If this is correct, you should be able to suspend from menu with screen not locked without issue. I'll update if I discover this is not the case

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, with Ubuntu 23.04, Ryzen, RTX2060. After suspend, the system would not seemingly resume, and the monitor signal would to return, having to click the hardware reset button. What fixed it for me in the end was: open Software and Updates, Additional Drivers, and change from the default  nvidia-driver-525 TO nvidia-driver-535. It's been working for about 24 hours and 3 sleeps. I hope I don't have to eat my words later.