# Suspend not working ubuntu 22.04 | Nvidia

Tags: drivers, nvidia, suspend, 22.04

I am using Lenovo Thinkpad with Nvidia graphic card, and I just installed the Ubuntu 22.04, and suspend isn't working.

When the laptop is suspended, it's all black screen with my power light keep blinking vigorously, and I hit the power button to turn it back on, nothing works, and I have to keep pressing the power button to turn it off.

I read a few answers and changed the graphic card driver, but nothing worked.

Comment: You've tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406114/cant-login-after-suspend-with-nouveau-wayland-22-04/1406212#1406212) ?

Comment: @ManOnTheMoon I have the exact same issue as OP, down to the type of hardware and the blirking issue, and no that doesn't help. I don't even have those services loaded.

Comment: @Tobia, while in the black screen, have you try pressing ctrl+alt+f1 simultaneously?

Comment: @ManOnTheMoon yes, I tried that, thanks. I tried everything I could think of, short of Print Screen kernel keys. But nevermind, I decided Ubuntu 22 is not for me anyways, I'm going back to Mint. I'll have to see if the issue is there too in the latest version, or not.

Comment: @Haseeb Ayub, try changing your driver to Noveau under Additional Driver tab in Software & Updates then reboot. When login there are two choices, Ubuntu and Ubuntu Xorg. Choose Ubuntu. fyi, it will say Wayland in Above under Settings after you login.

Comment: @Tobia, try the solution i've added for Haseed. I just switched back from Mint due to scaling limitation when using higher resolution monitor. And the solution i added fixed a number of things i had in the past.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 LTS can not resume after suspending](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1335689/ubuntu-20-04-lts-can-not-resume-after-suspending)