# Dual boot install of Ubuntu 20.04 with Nouveau or Nvidia drivers 510/470 fail to boot on new laptop with and without secureboot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia, uefi, live-usb

New Gigabyte Aorus 15 XE4 with RTX 3070ti. Windows 11 preinstalled. Added Samsung 970 Evo plus NVME SSD to dual boot install Ubuntu (or POPos).

The following has failed:

**Ubuntu 20.04:**

Installs from live usb (tried both rufus and etcher). Tried both secure boot disabled and enabled. Also tried proprietary Nvidia drivers AND Nouveau driver. When booting to os with nomodeset, only see black screen or blinking cursor. When not using nomodeset, boot hangs at splash gigabyte logo.

Also tried launching Ubuntu CLI recovery from GRUB. Managed to remove Nvidia 510 driver and install Nvidia 470 driver. Same result. Though it appears secure boot needs to be disabled for the 470. [Used this CLI method to purge and install.](https://askubuntu.com/a/1097453)

GRUB on new SSD works after install attempt. Can still launch Windows 11 no problems.

**POPos:**

Can't launch live usb made with rufus/posicle. Etcher fails all POPos's I tried (Nvidia/NonNvidia, 21.10/20.04). When same USB used on another computer, it works. On new laptop, booting from USB seems to hang right before GUI would load (after "popos session started" or something like that).
[Potentially related to this bug in nvidia 510](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=368152&sid=df437f937bceb4298850f1f44a8a3263&start=20).

I've used Ubuntu for years and was trying POPos for ease of Nvidia driver installs and hybrid GPU mode. Have resorted to trying Ubuntu again and would find some package to handle GPU switching later.

**Question:**

Is this laptop too new for linux drivers? Nouveau/Nvidia? Intel 12th Gen CPU?

Is UEFI system not happy with POPos even when secure boot is disabled? (THOUGH the BIOS/UEFI only allows me to set an admin password and delete key variables - I did check Hasleo Easu UEFI and it said Secure Boot disabled)

This seems to be graphics related. Anything else I should be trying?

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:**

Have tried Ubuntu 21.10 - Same issues as 20.04.

Also ubuntu Early release 22.04 doesn't install properly. Install seems to stop at firefox-locale-en package. It looks like it finishes but on reboot, it goes to GRUB command line or has kernel panic: `not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)`

Comment: This is an Ubuntu question & answer site. So we can help on Ubuntu issues, but POP!OS is off-topic. refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome.  It takes a while for Linux kernel & drivers to be updated to include very new hardware. Many vendors do not directly support Linux. Both Intel & AMD often have kernel updates in the newest kernel. But to have those in a distribution can take a bit of time. Best to use newest Ubuntu. You may want to install 22.04 when released in April.

Comment: Hi oldfred,I included my own attempts with POPos only for informative purposes.

I'll try the newest Ubuntu and report back. Thanks! And if I have to, I'll wait for 22.04.

Comment: You may try an early release version of 22.04 from https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/

Comment: Just tried 21.10 - Same problems as before.
Early release 22.04 is giving me a kernel panic after installing:
`not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)`
Did 22.04 not install correctly? I did get an error about firefox-en not working, but it continued and finished the install. I did have to enter the mok password that I made during install. It seemed to be okay.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a new laptop with 12th gen Intel processor alongwith RTX2050 GPU, and when I was trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS I encountered the same issue as yours (exactly the same! blinking cursor, dang it).

However today (2022/4/13) I tried installing the latest daily realease of 22.04 as ubfan1 suggested, and it worked, at least I could finish the installation and the system is booting without problem. Hence I suggest you give the latest release a try.

Comment: Hello. Since 22.04 does not exist this is not an answer. Installing a beta version is never an answer.