# Ubuntu 22.04 install nvidia driver "510.60" or "510.73"

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

Apparently my system upgraded from nvidia driver 510.60 to "510.73" and now again to "510.85".

I have problems with 510.85 though and would like to revert to 510.60 in best case scenario but if not possible at least revert back to 510.73.

This is the closest solution I found: [Ubuntu 18.10 : How can I install a specific NVIDIA drivers version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097433/ubuntu-18-10-how-can-i-install-a-specific-nvidia-drivers-version) but it's kind of old and I don't want to risk it.

So is there a more convenient way to install drivers from 2 versions back in Ubuntu 22.04?

Answer (score 1):

After searching the internet for some time I found this link which is the only one explaining how to manually install the needed version in Option 2: https://www.linuxcapable.com/install-nvidia-510-47-xx-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts/

Basically the method is that you need to download the drivers from the [NVIDIA's site](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/Find.aspx?lang=en-us) and use their documentation as to how to install the drivers on Linux as it is not straight forward. [Docs can be found here](http://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/470.74/README/installdriver.html#modulesigning).

Here are all the commands you need in order to install the drivers you download from NVIDIA:

```bash
sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential libglvnd-dev pkg-config dkms -y

sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf
```

Once inside the file add:

```
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
```

and then we continue with:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
sudo reboot now
```

After reboot you will be in terminal only mode, so you need to have another way to open this page to read the next commands, which are:

```
#navigate to the folder where you downloaded the drivers
sudo bash NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-510.{version-number}.run
sudo bash NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-510.*.run
```

After this you do "Continue" and only "Yes" until installation is finished (of course read what you click on and decide for your self)

then you finally you do:

```
sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
sudo reboot now
```

This should give you your desired NVIDIA older drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Use additional drivers on Gnome and there on:additional drivers -tab choose lower level driver and REBOOT.

Some cases:

1. select Noveau open source driver and apply
2. logout & login
3. select pro priority driver you want and apply
4. reboot

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I want to install a 510.65 version of the NVIDIA proprietary drivers and not go to Noveau.

Comment: And if NVIDIA has upgraded minor it is fairly problematic to get previous minor version. Have you tried NVIDIA 515? You could search .deb for 5.10.60 though I doubt you find it. Beta PPA might have it for download (you get link to it into /etc/apt/sources.list with: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa).